# input element send value with parameter name

Tags: html, forms, input

I have a simple form I created in HTML and has an input. Like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="setname">Name</label>
    <input id="setname"class="form-control" type="text"  />
</div>
```

I want the input to send the value entered with the parameter "Name". I read the input page for HTML but didn't see this option or maybe misunderstood what "sending the value" means for the input element.

This is probably simple but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: set a name attribute on your input element... <input name="name"....

Comment: Setting that will send this submitted value with whatever is in the "name" parameter?

Comment: yes, if you look at your network tab in developer mode on your browser you will see parameters that are sent by your form post... it will show like "name: whatever value entered"

Comment: Thank you @Liquidchrome for the explanation. Can you post as an answer so I can marked a resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is the "name" attribute on the form element and on submitting a post you will see the defined name of the name attribute show as the parameter.

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="my name"/>
```

On submit in network tab you will see:

test: my name

Answer (score 1):

Use the name attribute of input like this:

```
<input id="setname" class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" />
```

The server on the receiving end will get Name="whatever user entered in form" like this (example in php):

$name = $_POST["Name"];